# can i change data grid view combobox column into textbox column?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

```
if (ItemUnitsList.Count == 1)
{
        ((DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2]).DataSource = ItemUnitsList
        ((DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2]).DisplayMember = "UnitName";
        ((DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2]).ValueMember = "UnitId";
```

how i define default selected item to first index

```
}
else if (ItemUnitsList.Count > 1)
{       
        ((DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2]).DataSource = ItemUnitsList;
        ((DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2]).DisplayMember = "UnitName";
        ((DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2]).ValueMember = "UnitId";
```

how i define textchange event to this combobox column

```
}
else
{
        MessageBox.Show("NONE");
}
```

Comment: what do you want to do exactly?

Comment: set default selected index for the combobox column to be first index 
make textchange event for it

Answer (score 0):

Once a column is created you can't change its type. There is no `TextChanged` event for `DataGridViewComboboxColumn`.

If you want to validate any change use the `DataGridView.CellValidating` event.

To learn about `DataGridView` see the tips given [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/datagridview).

Comment: so if i want to change other column value depend on my combobox selection i couldn't ?!

Comment: @KOKO - you can change the value but not the type of other column. What do you want to achieve? Your problem is not clear.

Comment: how i do that changes ?

Comment: @KOKO - there are many ways to do it. I have added a link in my answer. You could get an fair idea about it from the linked page.